# How to use a variable(containing text in the form of array) while initializing a new array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```html
<span class="pop-ad-imagesName">'1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg'</span>
```

1)//say a span tag contain: '1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg'

```js
var imageNames = $(".pop-ad-imagesName").text();
var array = [imageNames];
```

if i do the above way, array takes imageNames as a single value, and when i alert the output, it displays:
'1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg'

2)but when i manually put the values:

```js
var array = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg'];
```

when i alert the output, it displays:
1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg

here the quotes are gone. and this way it works.. but i need the above way since i am getting the values from my view page in this way " $(".pop-ad-imagesName").text(); "

Comment: can u provide jsfiddle.

Comment: you want to display image name separately

Comment: what output exactly you want?

Comment: @Deena i need to generate random count out of those values..for eg: randomCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);     $('<img style="width:253px; height:400px" src="/Images/Advertisement/' + images[randomCount] + '">').appendTo('#dialog-confirm');

Comment: The biggest problem here is class name '.pop-ad-imagesName' (starts with dot). JQuery doesn't recognize it, so i guess it is invalid syntax....

Comment: var array = imageNames.split(', ');   // solved , i needed this . Thank you all.

Comment: you don't use .pop-ad-imagesName as class name . is access specifier for class .use class="pop-ad-imagesName"

Comment: @SuchitKumar Oh yes, my bad. I just copy pasted that and i forgot to remove dot ".". Thank you any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imageNames` is a string, so `var array = [imageNames];` only produce an array of one elements: ['1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg'].

Try this:

```
<span class="pop-ad-imagesName">1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg</span>

var imageNames = $(".pop-ad-imagesName").text();
var array = imageNames.split(', '); // ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg']
```

Comment: you don't use .pop-ad-imagesName as class name . is access specifier for class .use class="pop-ad-imagesName"

Comment: @SuchitKumar That was copied from OP's question. Fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just do that if you can:

```
<span class=".pop-ad-imagesName">1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg</span>
```

If you cannot, do:

```
var imageNames = $(".pop-ad-imagesName").text().replace(/\'/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
var imageNames = $(".pop-ad-imagesName").text().split(',');
alert( imageNames.join(' ') );
```

I hope this help.